# Plot gList side by side

Tags: r, plot, r-grid

I have 2 gList objects (grid) that plots fine when I do

```
grid.draw(plot1)
grid.draw(plot2)
```

But I want these to be side by side in a pdf. Something like

```
pdf(test.pdf)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:10)
plot(10:1)
dev.off
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: You example is really confusing. You want to put side by side  grid or basic graphics ?

Answer (score 4):

To arrange `grid` objects , you can use `grid.layout` within a viewport. here an example.

```
pushViewport(plotViewport(layout=grid.layout(1, 2),gp=gpar(cex=2)))
pushViewport(plotViewport(layout.pos.col=1))
  grid.draw(getPlot())
popViewport()
pushViewport(plotViewport(layout.pos.col=2, clip="on"))
  grid.draw(getPlot(col.fill='black',col.text='red',text='Rouge',x=0))
popViewport()
popViewport()
```

[image]

here `getPlot` is a function that retuen a `gList`;

```
getPlot <- function(col.fill="red",col.text='black',text="Noir",x=1){
  rect1 <- rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=col.fill))
  text1 <- textGrob(text,gp=gpar(col=col.text))
  text2 <- textGrob("&", x=x,gp=gpar(col=col.text))
  gList(rect1,text1,text2)
}
```