# Output Venn gList object and Network plot side-by-side

Tags: r, igraph, r-grid, venn-diagram

How can we plot Network plot (*igraph package plot*) and Venn diagram (*VennDiagram  gList object*) **side-by-side in one PDF page**?

Tried to follow below solutions, didn't work:
[Plot gList side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521671)
[Plot 2 tmap objects side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344454)
[Side-by-side Venn diagram using Vennerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314562)

Here is an example, which plots them in two pages. I used `grid.newpage()` to make it plot in separate pages, otherwise it gets plotted on top of each other.

```
library(grid)
library(igraph)
library(VennDiagram)

#network graph object
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE)

# venn plot object
plotVenn <- venn.diagram(
  list(A = 1:150, B = 121:170),
  filename = NULL)
class(plotVenn)
# [1] "gList"

# output to PDF, outputs into 2 pages, I need 1 page 2 plots side-by-side
pdf("temp.pdf")

#network
igraph::plot.igraph(g)

#venn
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(plotVenn)

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269538/venn-diagrams-in-multiple-figure-r perhaps useful

Comment: perhaps also useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929452/r-return-corrplot-as-object#27948707, to convert igraph plot to grob

Comment: @user20650 OK, I think this is a dupe to your earlier answers. Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking inspiration from the first link above, you can "trick" your way out by making coexist a "regular" `plot` and a `grid`:

```
pdf("temp.pdf", )
layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1))
igraph::plot.igraph(g)
plot.new()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2, widths=unit(c(0.5, 0.5), "npc"))))
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 2))
grid.draw(plotVenn)
popViewport(0)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Came up with below solution following links in the comments: [Venn diagrams in multiple figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269538)

```
pdf("temp.pdf")

layout(matrix(1:2, 1, byrow = TRUE))
#network
igraph::plot.igraph(g)

#network
frame()
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)
grid.draw(plotVenn)
popViewport(2)

dev.off()
```